# How to install GNU gettext on windows 7?

Tags: windows, gnu, gettext, django-i18n

I need to install version 0.15 or higher of GNU's gettext so that I can use some i18n feateres with django.

I've downloaded :

> http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.18.3.1.tar.gz

from https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

However I have no idea how to install it and there's no installation guide on their website.
How can I install it ?

Answer (score 26):

I'm maintaining a GitHub repository with Windows binaries of gettext and iconv (I just updated it to the latest gettext version: 0.19.3)

You can find it here: http://mlocati.github.io/gettext-iconv-windows/

To see how I compiled them (if you want to do it yourself) take a look at https://github.com/mlocati/gettext-iconv-windows

Comment: Thanks. Nice to have. Is it possible to provide ARM compiled libraries?  They are now almost more important than 32bit libraries.

Answer (score 12):

For windows, you may:

1. download gettext from
   http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/;
2. unzip both gettext-runtime and gettext-tools
3. add the bin folder to to PATH

Django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows

Comment: It works. I cannot thank you enough. I was about to quit. nothing was working before! thank you so much

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of versions, this is what I've downloaded:

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip

And:
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/gettext-tools-dev_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip

And added both **bin** folders to the Windows PATH.

Answer (score 3):

This is the actual link pointing to the Windows installation: http://mlocati.github.io/gettext-iconv-windows/ (v. 0.19.4)

I spent quite a while before found that there is the link pointing their from the github project mentioned by *mlokati*.

P.S. Here is the official instruction on this from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools from that NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gettext.Tools/

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of gettext setup is available here 
 -- -  https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

You can find a direct .exe setup file and then you can just add it to the environment variable PATH.