# use gettext on C# projects

Tags: c#, gettext

I've read a bit about the gettext. I believe it's a nice tool.

I've seen it's possible to use it with PHP projects.

I wonder if it is possible to use gettext also in with C#?

Comment: A quick search reveals http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985482/how-to-install-gnu-gettext-on-windows-7

Answer (score -1):

There is a C# version as well and it can be used with both `.resource` and `.dll` files. Sample use with a 'singleton' type of approach:

> Define a static holding the ResourceManager instance:

```
public static GettextResourceManager MyResourceManager =
  new GettextResourceManager("domain-name");
```

> All classes containing internationalized strings then contain

```
private static String _(String s) { return Util.MyResourceManager.GetString(s); }
```

> and this lets you use it like this, quite clean:

```
Console.WriteLine(_("Operation completed."));
```

Note that it needs some exception handling etc. and also introduces a lot of code duplication, which you can sort in different ways.

You can find all the usage details and context in the manual itself:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/C_0023.html#C_0023

Comment: instead of just sharing a link, i think it would be much better if some example was shown here. The link might not exist in future for others.

Comment: Somewhere in that page you can read: "But beware: as of this writing (January 2004), the monoresgen converter is quite buggy."

Comment: @AvikB well, there is a full description, so if it's you negging the answer, it's uncool