# Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed

Tags: python, django

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlJ8cGbk8ps i followed this video and when i do this command
`django-admin makemessages -l ar` it gives me this error `CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.` and i have installed `pip install python-gettext`
any aswers?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to install `msguniq` on your system. For a debian system, you can likely do this with `sudo apt-get install gettext`.

Comment: i am widows not apple :-( @willem-van-onsem

Comment: Debian is not Apple. Debian is a linux distro.

Answer (score 17):

> and i have installed `pip install python-gettext`

The problem is *not* the Python binding of gettext, it is the gettext library itself. This is not a Python library, but a system library.

You can install this on a debian-like system (Debian, Ubuntu, Raspbian, and Knoppix):

```
sudo apt-get install gettext
```

For other operating systems, you can probably build it from the source files, or look [for a repository that makes binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26505549/67579).

Comment: it gives me this
sudo: The term 'sudo' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @YehiaYasser: as specified this is for Debian systems: `sudo` is a way to get root access to the system. For Windows you will likely have to build `gettext` manually, or look for someone who made an installer from the source code.

Comment: do you know how to build it ?

Comment: Apparently someone did that and made installation packages: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

Comment: it does not work man i extracted the file to the C:\Program Files\gettext-utils

Comment: @YehiaYasser: but you do not need to extract it, you need to *build* it too. You should include `msguniq` in the `PATH` variable. I don't know if the installer automates that somehow, I'm happy I didn't had to work on Windows machines for the last 12 years.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226146/discussion-between-yehia-yasser-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: @YehiaYasser: you likely should add the `bin` directory to the `PATH` environment variable, such that the command `msguniq` will invoke the program in the `bin` directory.

Comment: done i have added this path C:\Program Files\gettext-utils\bin to the environment variable

Comment: @YehiaYasser: so if you type `msguniq` in a terminal, this invokes the program?

Comment: in witch terminal

Comment: @YehiaYasser: in a shell... Just like you invoke for example `python`.....

Comment: it give me this 
msguniq: The term 'msguniq' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @YehiaYasser: then it is not in the PATH, or it at least did not "ripple" through the system: https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/yehiayasserahmed/this is my profile can we talk on messenger?

Comment: i dont understand anything please help me

Comment: please give me an answer